# Howto move an element in xml only when a value inside element matches with xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

This one I'm struggling with for a few day's now. I can solve little parts of the puzzle but when trying to merge it into one xslt stylesheet I'm completely lost.

The source xml looks like this (simplified)

```
<tr>
  <pic>
    <hs>
      <spot>
        <posit>
          <pan>28</pan>
          <tilt>44</tilt>
        </posit>
        <id>_flare</id>
      </spot>
      <spot>
        <posit>
          <pan>6</pan>
          <tilt>7</tilt>
        </posit>
      </spot>
      <spot>
        <posit>
          <pan>4</pan>
          <tilt>8</tilt>
        </posit>
        <id>Point01</id>
      </spot>
    </hs>
    <snd>
      <level>1</level>
      <sound>
        <loop>1</loop>
      </sound>
    </snd>
  </pic>
</tr>
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
<tr>
  <pic>
    <hs>
      <spot>
        <posit>
          <pan>6</pan>
          <tilt>7</tilt>
        </posit>
      </spot>
      <spot>
        <posit>
          <pan>4</pan>
          <tilt>8</tilt>
        </posit>
        <id>Point01</id>
      </spot>
    </hs>
    <snd>
      <level>1</level>
      <sound>
        <loop>1</loop>
      </sound>
      <lf>
          <pos>
            <pan>28</pan>
            <tilt>44</tilt>
          </pos>
          <col>#ffffff</col>
      </lf>
    </snd>
  </pic>
</tr>
```

I think it needs some explanation. Only the "spot" with an "id" that matches "_flare" in "hs" should be moved and added to the "snd" element. It also has to be reformatted from:

```
  <spot>
    <posit>
      <pan>28</pan>
      <tilt>44</tilt>
    </posit>
    <id>_flare</id>
  </spot>
```

to

```
  <lf>
      <pos>
        <pan>28</pan>
        <tilt>44</tilt>
      </pos>
      <col>#ffffff</col>
  </lf>
```

I appreciate a hint in the right direction to get me going again !

Regards,

AHG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on michael.hor257k's solution, you can leave it unchanged and simply add one more template for handling the id's:

```
<xsl:template match="spot">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[local-name()!='id']"/>
        <id>
            <xsl:text>Point</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(preceding-sibling::spot[not(id='_flare')])+1,'00')"/>
        </id>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The old id's will be ignored, and each element gets a new one, starting from "Point01".

Comment: Thanks Kimme. You are right, this one works better than mine, thank you very much, helps me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spot[id='_flare']"/>

<xsl:template match="snd">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../hs/spot[id='_flare']" mode="add"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spot" mode="add">
    <lf>
        <pos>
            <xsl:copy-of select="posit/pan | posit/tilt"/>
        </pos>
        <col>#ffffff</col>
    </lf>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Damn! You were faster than me. ;-)

Comment: Actually, aside from the identity transform part, both have the same amount of code bc the algorithm is exactly the same.

Comment: @Kimmy I meant mainly your first 4 templates, that can be replaced by one. Also, `./` can be removed.

Comment: Uh, Ok! And what about the `processing-instruction()` part? I mean usually you don't have any processing instructions, but how can I handle them when wanting to achieve an identity transform?

Comment: @Kimmy Processing instructions are matched by `node()`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- Catch-all templates -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- delete spot from the top -->
    <xsl:template match="spot[id[text()='_flare']]"/>
    <!-- add spot to the bottom -->
    <xsl:template match="snd">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//spot[id[text()='_flare']]" mode="addToBottom"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="spot[id[text()='_flare']]" mode="addToBottom">
        <lf>
            <pos>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./posit/*"/>
            </pos>
            <col>#ffffff</col>
        </lf>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Kimmy and michael.hor257k , my deep respect for these very fast answers ! They both work very well and give me the right output. I'm still amazed how short a xslt stylesheet can be for these kind of puzzels .... I'm still learning new features and possibilities ...

Comment: Next time I'll beat michael.hor257k! ;-)

Comment: I do have an extra challenge =). This is going a little step further. I managed to reorder the xml file, but the resulting file had some problems. I pinpointed this to the missing "<id>Point01</id>" in the outputs "hs/spot" elements. Every "spot" element should have one "<id>Point01</id>" but they should be unique in the "hs" element. The first will be Point01 the second Point02 etc. etc.    Can this be done with xslt ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself on the last  question.

My xslt stylesheet is now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spot[id='_flare']"/>

<xsl:template match="snd">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../hs/spot[id='_flare']" mode="add"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="spot" mode="add">
    <lf>
        <pos>
            <xsl:copy-of select="posit/pan | posit/tilt"/>
        </pos>
        <col>#ffffff</col>
    </lf>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id"/>

<xsl:template match="hs/spot" >
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<id> <xsl:value-of select="concat('Point',count(preceding::spot)+1)"/> </id>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There might be a smarter way though ....

Comment: Have a look at my other answer, posted 1 minute after yours. Your solution works concerning the IDs, but it doesn't move the "_flare" item to the bottom any more.